# Docker AddSigningCredential BIO_new_file:no such file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I just included in my solution an AddSigningCredential and when I run the solution in Visual Studio in Debug mode I have no problem. But, if I run the solution in Visual Studio in Release mode and docker-compose I get an error saying cannot found the certificate.  Currently the certificate in inside the wwwroot: `@"wwwroot\my-cert.pfx"`

Comment: Is it actually included in the deployment? Also, that would mean your cert is downloadable by anyone and they could have a good crack at compromising the private key.

Comment: @mackie so what would be the solution?

Comment: Include the file but don't expose it to the internet in the document root. Did you confirm that is it actually getting included in the published app?

Comment: @mackie yes, it does